# C# Realizar consulta con join y luego mostrarla en un datagrid

Tags: c#, join, datagridview

Desde ya les agradezco, mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo mi programa que realiza una consulta a la base de datos sqlserver, la consulta es con join, por lo tanto el resultado no lo puedo guardar en una lista Fuertemente Tipada, ya que tengo campos de dos tablas distintas, como haría en este caso para poder mostrar ese resultado en mi programa?, muchas gracias!

Comment: Coloca tu codigo para ayudarte, pero seguro que es con un objeto anonimo

Comment: Que exista un Join, no implica que no puedas crear una clase fuertemente tipada para almacenar la información..

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Coincido pero quizas, luego de la consulta no lo vuelve a usar y crearia una clase solo por una consulta que quiere mostrar, tiene que ver si lo mejor es crear un objeto anonimo o crear una clase nueva para luego usarla o hacer herencia.